# How would call a function that calls "by-name" as an argument in scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, method-call, scala-option, pass-by-name

I'm pretty new to scala and still in the early days of learning. I was reading an article that had an example like so:

```scala
def example(_list: List[Positions], function: Position => Option[Path]): Option[Path] = _list match {...}
```

**NB**

- Position is a `(Int,Int)`
- Path is a `List( Position )`

From what I understand, this method will hold:

- `list of positions`
- `Option[Path]`

and will return `Option[Path]`

What I don't understand is how are we supposed to call this method?

I tried this:

`example(Nil, Option( 0,0 ) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of `function` is `Position => Option[Path]` - this is **not** a by-name argument, it's a *type* that is equivalent to `Function1[Position, Option[Path]]` - a **function** that takes one argument of type `Position` and returns an `Option[Path]`.

So, when you call it you can pass an *anonymous function* with matching type, e.g.:

```
example(Nil, pos => Some(List(pos)))
example(Nil, pos => Some(List()))
example(Nil, pos => None)
```

You can also pass a *method* with matching type, e.g.:

```
object MyObj {
  def posToPaths(position: Position): Option[Path] = Some(List(position))

  example(Nil, posToPaths)
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much Zohar. Really appreciate it for clearing that misunderstanding